# Format the dbcontext sql query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, dbcontext

I have a dbContext set up that works when using the `.find()` command to search on the key value.  For example, the following statement will return the mass value for the key that matches `UnitID` passed in:

```
double Mass = dbMTG.MountingSpecs.Find(UnitID).Mass;
```

How do I return the `Mass` value when searching on a value other than the key?  I've played a little bit with sqlquery, without any success.  I've tried

`double Mass = dbMTG.MountingSpecs.SqlQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Mass WHERE Class == 3");`

I've seen a number of post about sqlquery but none of them are using dbcontext. Maybe there is a good reason for that?

Comment: Turns out my biggest problem was my class name not matching the db table name.  Once I fixed that I check out the three answers provided at the time and found them all to work.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use some simple LINQ to accomplish this:

```
var Mass = dbMTG.MountingSpecs
           .Where(m => m.Class == 3)
           .Select(m => m.Mass)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure there is only one result I'd say you could do

```
double Mass = dbMTG.MountingSpecs
      .SqlQuery<double>("SELECT DISTINCT Mass WHERE Class == 3")
      .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Nullable<double> Mass = dbMTG.MountingSpecs.Where(spec => spec.Class == 3).Select(spec => spec.Mass).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```